# Magento 2 : At Which Place Final Price of Product is Set for Globally?

Tags: magento2, price

**I want to know for Entry point of Product final price calculation, those will be used globally in site like listing page,catalog page, shopping cart page,minicart.**

I have to customize for product price, Is there any place we can set price and its used in global.

Where i can find final price of product is set(after special price, catalog/shopping rule if available) in magento 2?

Is there any place where product final price is calculated and its working for magento site Globally in all pages?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share what you actually wanted to change as this will determine which approach to take?

Comment: i want to set custom price base 10 based on current price.

Comment: also i have store with multi currency, in Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php getPrice function() each time display base price for all currency, i have to find where final price is calculated.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya I want to get price after tax including . which file and function return final price with tax included ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, seem that you want to custom price on your shop. We should see some useful methods for customizing price.

**vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Currency.php**

```
 public function formatPrecision(
        $price,
        $precision,
        $options = [],
        $includeContainer = true,
        $addBrackets = false
    ) {
       ......
    }
```

**vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/PriceCurrency.php**

```
 public function format(
            $amount,
            $includeContainer = true,
            $precision = self::DEFAULT_PRECISION,
            $scope = null,
            $currency = null
        ) {
            ......
        }

 public function convertAndRound($amount, $scope = null, $currency = null, $precision = self::DEFAULT_PRECISION)
 {
        ......
 }
```

**vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Format.php**

```
 public function getPriceFormat($localeCode = null, $currencyCode = null)
 {
   ......
 }
```

For sample **di.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Directory\Model\Currency">
        <plugin name="modify_around_precision" type="Vendor\YourModule\Model\Directory\Plugin\Precision" />
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Directory\Model\PriceCurrency">
        <plugin name="modify_around_format" type="Vendor\YourModule\Model\Directory\Plugin\Format" />
        <plugin name="modify_around_round" type="Vendor\YourModule\Model\Directory\Plugin\PriceRound" />
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Locale\Format">
        <plugin name="modify_around_price_format" type="Vendor\YourModule\Model\Locale\Plugin\ModifyPriceFormat" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: There is a good sample here: https://github.com/Magento-Japan/m2-jplocalize/tree/master/price

Comment: i have store with multi currency, in Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php getPrice function() each time display base price for all currency, i have to find where final price is calculated.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh wouldn't it be better to use Currency.php instead of Precision.php?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the template that renders the final price of products, then bringing this (`magento2/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml`) [file](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml) to your theme should do the job.

And this [file](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php#L154) (`magento2/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php`) is probably where the final price is calculated.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If we here change price of product then its automatically set whole site, if i am change price from model file, its same display in cart page also?