# Magento 2 overwrite Zend_Currency

Tags: magento2, currency

I want to change the price precision for showing 4 decimal points. I can see that this can be done by overwriting the

```
vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Currency.php
```

How can I overwrite the **Currency.php** to my local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Magento 2 has implemented its own currency module.

**vendor/magento/framework/Currency.php**

```
class Currency extends \Zend_Currency implements CurrencyInterface
{
   ......
}
```

If we're going to custom the price precision, we should see [this guide](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131255/magento-2-at-which-place-final-price-of-product-is-set-for-globally/131300#131300).

Comment: Thanks @Khoa TruongDinh,
I have extend this class and solved my problem

Comment: @Khoa TruongDinh, Could you please let me know for override, vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/pa.xml this xml file.

Comment: @Rakesh you can explain more about your current situation?

Comment: I want to do same functionality in magento 2, refer link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270992/magento-decimal-price-in-spanish-language-display-dot-instead-comma

Comment: @Khoa TruongDinh, Already i have post question, http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147332/how-to-remove-comma-from-price-in-spanish-locale-for-magento-2

Comment: @Rakesh Ok! I see. I will try.