# How to Remove comma from price in spanish locale for magento 2

Tags: magento2, price, multistore

**Website with two Stores with different language.**

```
1. English Language
2. Spanish Language
```

I have issue with Spanish Language store Price/Currency display as decimal Comma instead of dot.

**Please refer this images for different sections,**

[image]

In above picture for spanish store, `Price display as $52,00 instead of $52.00` for Product Page.

[image]

In above picture,`Subtotal price display as $1.344,00 instead of $1,344.00 for spanish locale in checkout page`

[image]

```
In Cart Page, Price also display as comma instead of Dot decimal.
```

> For English store Pricing are display Proper format.

**I want to set Pricing in spanish locale same as English locale.**

> For Spanish Locale store, Pricing display as Comma instead of decimal
>   point and Display Decimal Point instead of Comma.

Same link for magento 1, [magento 1 spanish locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270992/magento-decimal-price-in-spanish-language-display-dot-instead-comma)
How to do same in magento 2?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you try change locale for spanish store view?

Comment: @KAndy, Any suggestion for this will be appericiated.