# magento 2: remove trailing 0 from checkout item price

Tags: magento2, checkout, blocks

I am trying to remove trailing 0s for all price outputs on the checkout page. `ex. $125.00 outputs as $125`

Inside one of the templates for the checkout page `vendor/magento/module-weee/view/frontend/templates/item/price/row.phtml` there is a function `$block->formatPrice()` which is located in `Magento\Tax\Block\Item\Price\Renderer`

```
public function formatPrice($price)
{
    $item = $this->getItem();
    if ($item instanceof QuoteItem) {
        return $this->priceCurrency->format(
            $price,
            true,
            PriceCurrencyInterface::DEFAULT_PRECISION,
            $item->getStore()
        );
    } elseif ($item instanceof OrderItem) {
        return $item->getOrder()->formatPrice($price);
    } else {
        return $item->getOrderItem()->getOrder()->formatPrice($price);
    }
}
```

Here the constant `PriceCurrencyInterface::DEFAULT_PRECISION` is set to `2` by default which causes the price to output with two trailing 0s.

I want to remove all trailing 0s after the decimal point from the price but am not sure what is the best strategy to do so.  I attempted to create a plugin via di to strip the 0s using `afterFormatPrice()`

```
public function afterFormatPrice(\Magento\Weee\Block\Item\Price\Renderer $block, $price)
{
    return $this->stripTrailingZero($price);
}
```

however the return value includes html markup, making it messy to format the number.  I could overwrite the class, but want to avoid doing so.

Does anyone know a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my side, I think it's better if we override from the back end side. We need to change the price precision. We can read more: [Magento 2 : At Which Place Final Price of Product is Set for Globally?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131255/magento-2-at-which-place-final-price-of-product-is-set-for-globally/131300#131300). There is a free module [here](https://github.com/Magento-Japan/m2-jplocalize/tree/master/price).

On the front page, you can use Javascript to remove trailing 0, you should override  this file: `Magento\Catalog\view\base\web\js\price-utils.js`.

Comment: I used plugin approach with aroundFormatPrecision().  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For the order summary section of the checkout page, the price is being formatted in javascript. You'll need to override the `Magento\Catalog\view\base\web\js\price-utils.js` script using requirejs. Heres how to do it:

Copy `Magento\Catalog\view\base\web\js\price-utils.js` to your module in `Your\Module\view\web\frontend\js\price-utils.js`. In this file you will modify the `formatPrice` function to get the desired result. I replaced the last line of the function with this:

```
pattern = pattern.replace('%s', r).replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
return pattern.replace('.00', '');
```

Now create the file `Your\Module\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js` with this content:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils" : "Your_Module/js/price-utils"
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: this is helpful but not the area i am looking to format.

Comment: you can do this in theme with `Your\Theme\web\js\price-utils.js`
`Your\Theme\requirejs-config.js`
and change `Your_Module/js/price-utils` to `js/price-utils`